# Python docx documenation

Tags: python, python-docx

I am looking for resources that help me interpret python documentation effectivley. In particular, I am  reading through the pythondocx module documentation, but am finding it hard to understand some sections.

As an example, when I read the  [Style Objects Section](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/style.html#styles-objects)
, I am confused by lines such as `class docx.styles.styles.Styles` and what it is actually saying.

Any ideas on  what I can do the to interpret documentation better?

Answer (score 1):

I honestly think reading pythondocx module documentation is a bit of overkill. 
The hard part of reading python documentation is understanding the specific logic of how objects and builtin's are organized in python. The best place to start, IMHO, is the index [Python 3.8.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) together with [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) and [collections](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html).

Even if you had studied other common languages before, like Java and C#, their API's are laid out in a different style. Each takes its own time for the reader to get used to. The python docs were written to be self-explanatory and after an initial learning curve that isn't especially steep the docs start making lots of sense.

Comment: I should note that I am not reading python-docx docs for the hell of it, I actually need to use it for work. I am trying to solve my problem by referring to the documentation, but have noticed I struggle with interpretations Thanks for the advice though mate

Comment: I've gone through the exact same. My best advice: this is not a compiled/strongly-typed language so the signature-syntax in the docs is less important than finding&running concrete examples through your debugger. Get a grasp/example on how *kwargs is used in a multiple inheritance, then add a simple meta-class if you can. It tends to be an altogether much smoother ride after that...